# How to type ^G (Ctrl + G) in Code Editors

Tags: batch-file, visual-studio-code, cmd, notepad++

I am trying to create a batch file that plays the beep sound of Bell character. Whenever I try typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, it triggers the Go To Dialog. I have tried Notepad, Notepad++ and VSCode.

Directly typing `echo Ctrl+G` in the command line works but I want to run it through a batch file.

If typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> is not possible, is there any other way of playing that beep sound?

Comment: If you type, into the command line, `echo x` then press Ctrl-G, then carry on typing `x >c:\temp\a.txt`, press return, then open c:\temp\a.txt you'll find your bell char sandwiched between two x - you can copy and pste it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are many ways to do that

- In cmd type `echo echo ^G >bell.bat` (i.e. **press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>** after typing `echo echo`  then redirect the output to a file) and open `bell.bat` in any text editor and continue editing the file
- In Notepad++ you can type `07`, select it then open menu *Plugins > Converter > HEX -> ASCII*
- Use [Alt Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alt_code). In any text editor press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>
- ...

In PowerShell it's even easier. Simply run `[char]7` or print it in any echo command and you'll hear a bell. You can also do that from cmd by running `powershell -C [char]7` but it's recommended to use PowerShell instead

In PowerShell you also have [`[console]::Beep()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-6.0#system-console-beep) or [`[console]::Beep(frequency, duration)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.beep?view=net-6.0#system-console-beep(system-int32-system-int32)). For example to beep 2 seconds of [A440](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A440_(pitch_standard)) run

```
[console]::Beep(440, 2000)
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
::Define a Linefeed variable
(set LF=^
%=-=%
)
  
for /f eol^=^%LF%%LF%^ delims^= %%A in (
   'forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo(0x07"'
) do set "BEL=%%A"

echo %BEL%
```

this will allow to get the BEL character without worrying about editor settings and how the special character will be saved.

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe - here the technique is described: https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3857

Answer (score 2):

> *"is there any other way of playing that beep sound?"*

Why not?

`> RunDLL32 User32.dll,MessageBeep`